# HP laserjet shows offline on server but is pingable

Tags: printer

We have three HP Laserjet 9000n printers, in addition to others, networked on Server 2003 R2. The three printers are wired through a Linksys mini switch. All three printers have appropriate drivers installed and have over 6 million pages each, on them. No configuration changes have been made.

Last week, our "A" printer showed up as offline in the printer management console on our server but the printer itself shows ready on the user display. In addition, the printer is pingable and the configuration page is accessible through the browser; the configuration page shows the printer as ready, as well. We can print a configuration page from the printer itself but not send a test page from any network host or the server.

On Monday, our "B" printer spit the bit in this manner as well. The "C" printer is still working fine.

We have:

1. Uninstalled/reinstalled printer and drivers
2. Changed cables
3. Played musical ports on the switch
4. Changed out the NIC's on the printers
5. Changed network ports/IP
6. Restarted the spooler service
7. Started sacrificing small animals

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this applies to 2003 R2:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946198

Comment: Go into Configure Port in the printer properties and disable SNMP, restart print spooler, then see if it shows the printer online

Comment: Many thanks. That did the trick. The goats and cows thank you too. I don't know how to upvote you for this.

Comment: Other random trivia on the HP print driver's SNMP issues (at least, with the universal print driver): if you have enough printers (maybe 50) with SNMP enabled on the server, the SNMP queries to all devices will retry constantly and with such frequency as to essentially create a denial-of-service condition on the server - I guess the SNMP error handling code ain't that great.  @user78940, make an answer with that!

Comment: @Shane Really? We have over 300 HP LJs using the UPD on a single Windows server and the statues report as expected.  Could you provide a link to this issue's details? I've not seen it, but would certainly prefer to avoid it.

Comment: @jscott I don't think I ever found a bug listing, but it was reproducible across 3 different print servers - just with SNMP blocked or otherwise unavailable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into Configure Port in the printer properties and disable SNMP, restart print spooler, then see if it shows the printer online.

Comment: "An error occurred during port configuration." "This operation is not supported."